# Is it possible to position views with Auto Layout in Interface Builder so that if a label is empty the other views will not keep the space?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIView` I want to position with Auto Layout in Interface Builder, and the view consists of several labels. Here's an attempted textual representation:

```
            |
-- First label with some text -------------------
            |
-- Second label that may not have text in it ----
            |
-- Third label with some text -------------------
            |
```

It basically has the three labels positioned with around 20pt between them and 20pt from the edges.

However – and here's the kicker – the second label often has no text in it at all. It's somewhat of an optional extra description the view could have.

Is it possible to say something along the lines of "Position like above, but if the second label isn't present, put that 20pt spacing in between the first and third label.". I want to make sure there's not an odd gap when the second label is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove that second label from the superview to have its constraints disappear. You can add a lower priority constraint between the third and first labels that give them the spacing you want if there is no second label. In code, you will need to check if the second able has no text, and if so, remove it from its superview. This will cause the lower priority constraint to be satisfied, and move the third label up.

**After Edit:**

Another way to do this without removing anything, is to make the vertical spacing constraint between the third and first labels in the first place, instead of one between the third and second labels. Make an IBOutlet to that constraint, and change its constant value in code if the second label has no text. The second label will still be there, but the third label will be on top of it.

Comment: Is there a way to have its constraints disappear without removing it from its superview? I ask because the description can come in over the network after it has loaded so it would be nice to not have to rebuild it.

Comment: @DougSmith, you could remove the constraints specific to that label in code if you want (not sure where the label would end up, probably at 0,0). I don't know if that's any better in your case. What do you mean by "have to rebuild it"?

Comment: Well I don't want to have to recreate the label and its attributes in code later and then rebuild all the constraints and set them. Maybe I'll just remove them both in `viewDidLoad` and save them into variables for restoring later.

Comment: @DougSmith, I added an update with another simpler way to do this.